# What user-mode and kernel mode driver does Windows using WDDM drivers load for DirectDraw HAL?

Tags: windows, drivers, kernel, directx, direct3d

I started using Process Explorer to look at the DLLs referred by the programs.

Surprisingly, applications utilising only DirectDraw HAL don't seem to call any graphics related library/driver. It is only Direct3D where I can see the Nvidia "nvd3dum.dll" being loaded.

What's going on? Is Process Explorer missing something, is there a better way to check this? Is there a generic way to determine the library/driver being loaded?

I don't have much other ideas; I decided to go through the driver files to get a description in them related to DirectDraw but I found none. All references I got to was for Direct3D or other APIs.

On the flip side, an old XPDM-based Intel driver for XP has a file with with description being a DirectDraw driver but I don't find any file which has a description that it is ia Direct3D driver - this driver has D3D support.

Comment: According to [DirectDraw Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/directdraw-architecture) you should be seeing `ddraw.dll`.

Comment: The differences between Windows XP and Windows 10 is significant in this regard, a crash with a display driver on Windows XP, would crash the NT kernel. Comparing Windows XP and Windows 10 in this regard provides no useful information at all for that reason alone. WDDM on modern versions of Windows is significantly better compared to the version built-into XP

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I am aware that the changes over the two OS is large and they handle the driver architecture differently. I didn't mean to compare the two, I wanted to highlight that my method to look into driver files summary wasn't useful for my purpose.